# Splitting date in csv file

Tags: pandas, date

I have a csv file having the following with a `Date` columns having the following format `2002-08-31` so `YEAR-MONTH-DAY`.

I would like to split this columns in 3 different columns in such a way that the table will have a `YEAR` column a `MONTH` column and a `DAY` column.
Does anyone knows how to achieve that

Answer (score 1):

If you use Pandas 0.15 or above, you can take advantage of the `dt`accessor like this

```
df['Year'] = df['Date'].year
df['Month'] = df['Date'].month
df['Day'] = df['Date'].day
```